# Recommended replica set config in Azure

Tags: linux, mongodb, azure, dns

We're running MongoDB on Azure and are in the process of setting up a production replica set (no shards) and I'm looking at the recommendations here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-linux-in-azure/

And I see the replica set config is such that the members will talk to each other via external IP addresses - isn't this going to 1) incur additional Azure costs since the replication traffic goes thru the external IPs and 2) incur replication latency because of the same?

At least one of our applications that will talk to Mongo will be running outside of Azure.

AWS has a feature where external DNS names when looked up from the VMs resolve to internal IPs and when resolved from outside, to the external IP which makes things significantly easier :)  In my previous job, I ran a fairly large sharded mongodb in AWS...

I'm curious what your folks recommendations are?  I had two ideas...

1) configure each mongo host with an external IP (not entirely sure how to do this in Azure but I'm sure it's possible...) and configure DNS to point to those IPs externally.  Then configure each VM to have an /etc/hosts file that points those same names to internal IP addresses.  Run Mongo on port 27017 in all cases (or really whatever port).  This means that the set does replication traffic over internal IPs but external clients can talk to it using the same DNS names.

2) simiilar to #1 but run mongo on 3 different ports but with only one external IP address and point all three external DNS names to this external IP address.  We achieve the same results but it's cleaner I think.

Thanks!
Jerry

Answer (score 0):

There is no *best* way, but let me clarify a few of the "objective" points:

- There is no charge for any traffic moving between services / VMs / storage in the same region. Even if you connect from one VM to the other using `servicename.cloudapp.net:port`. No charge.
- Your choice whether you make the mongod instances externally accessible. If you do create external endpoints, you'll need to worry about securing those endpoints (e.g. Access Control Lists). Since your app is running outside of Azure, this is an option you'll need to consider. You'll also need to think about how to encrypt the database traffic (mongodb Enterprise edition supports SSL; otherwise you need to build mongod yourself).
- Again, if you expose your mongod instances externally, you need to consider whether to place them within the same cloud service (sharing an ip address, getting separate ports per mongod instance), or multiple cloud services (unique ip address per cloud service). If the mongod instances are within the same cloud service, they can then be clustered into an *availability set* which reduces downtime by avoiding host OS updates simultaneously across all vm's, and splits vm's across multiple fault domains).
- In the case where your app/web tier live within Azure, you can use internal IP addresses, with both your app and mongodb vm's within the same virtual network.

Comment: Reading between the lines a bit here then - the names in the replica set config need to be both resolvable and reachable from all of the members and all clients whether internal or external to Azure, right?  Is  there recommended way to do this assuming we have external clients?  I made a few suggestions in my original question but both seem a bit hacky to me...  I see there's a SaaS MongoDB offering - how is it setup there?  And if I intend eventually to shard and run mongos external to Azure, all of the shard and config servers need to be resolvable and reachable from both?

Comment: Also, I understand there's no charge for the replication traffic if I configure the set with external IPs but there will be a latency hit meaning more replication lag or is this not significant?